# Javascript: starting new line one pressing enter key: using <br> to imitate <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When pressing return key to create new lines in contenteditable div, I somehow need to use br tag instead of div tag (default way) to make a new line in contenteditable div, the behavior of the code works fine but somehow there has a bug I can't fixed, That is, if putting caret at the start of line2 (in between line1 and line3) and press the enter key, the caret will move to line3 fails to create a new br tag and create new line, which is not good since it is not the same as div tag do.

The result I want is that after pressing enter key at line2, the caret should move to the previous "line3" position while the "line3" should move to line4.

Could anyone help figure out why there's no new br tag has been made and how to fix this?

```js
function getSelectionTextInfo(el) {
    var atStart = false, atEnd = false;
    var selRange, testRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            testRange = selRange.cloneRange();

            testRange.selectNodeContents(el);
            testRange.setEnd(selRange.startContainer, selRange.startOffset);
            atStart = (testRange.toString() == "");

            testRange.selectNodeContents(el);
            testRange.setStart(selRange.endContainer, selRange.endOffset);
            atEnd = (testRange.toString() == "");
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        selRange = document.selection.createRange();
        testRange = selRange.duplicate();

        testRange.moveToElementText(el);
        testRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selRange);
        atStart = (testRange.text == "");

        testRange.moveToElementText(el);
        testRange.setEndPoint("StartToEnd", selRange);
        atEnd = (testRange.text == "");
    }

    return {atEnd};
}

$('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
    // trap the return key being pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var selInfo = getSelectionTextInfo(this);
        if(selInfo.atEnd===true){
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, ' <br><br>');
        return false;
        }
        else if(selInfo.atEnd===false){
                 document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, ' <br>');
        return false;
        }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ninjia" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">line1<br><br>line3</div>
```

Comment: you're getting the 'in middle' in your console if you do that

Comment: @RachelGallen I just delete the console.log() function since I made it for testing and become confusing in the example.

Comment: i mean i just ran it and i got 'in middle' displaying in the console

Comment: but only in between those two lines

Comment: well deleting the console log isn't going to solve it. It does break but there's already something on the next line. If you want it to consider it as not in the middle but at the end if there's already a dbl break, well you'll have to code it to put in 2 br tags if that is the case. Its just a check

Comment: @RachelGallen if using two br tags, if put cursor between "lin"and"e3" and press enter key, it creates two line, which is not desirable. If put cursor at line2, the thing is it creates no br tag when the code asks it to creates one.

Comment: actually your code as is already breaks lines mid-sentence

Comment: results of testing posted

Answer (score 0):

I recommend usage of some Open source program that harmonize the behaviours of `contenteditable` or use an textarea element instead, and after edit replace \n with `<br>` tags